# how can make this struct smarter

Tags: c#, .net

I have this struct which is part of of a class.

```
  public struct PartStruct
    {
        public string name;
        public string filename;
        public string layer2D;
        public string layer3D;
        public TypeOfPart type;
        public int hight;
        public int depth;
        public int length;
        public int flooroffset;
        public int width;
        public int cellingoffset;
    }
```

each instance of this struct will represent a part with different properties, I'm using just one struct type because I have this function:

```
public void insert(Partstruct part){//large code to insert the part}
```

example:

```
Partstruct monitor = new Partstruct();
monitor.name = "mon1";
monitor.file = "default monitor file name.jpg";//this is a const for each new monitor
monitor.TypeofPart = monitor;
monitor.layer2d = "default monitor layer";//this will be the same for each new monitor.
```

etc..

```
Partstruct keyboard= new Partstruct();
keyboard.name = "keyboard1";
keyboard.file = "default keyboard file name.jpg";//this is a const for each new keyboard
keyboard.TypeofPart = keyboard;
keyboard.layer2d = "default keyboard 2d layer";//this will be the same for each new keyboard.
keyboard.layer3d = "default keyboard 3d layer"//this will be the same for each new keyboard.
```

etc..

```
insert(monitor);
insert(keyboard);
```

can I do this in a smarter way? I'm using .net 3.5

Comment: What about a base type and inheritance or an interface type? It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve - can you comment more on what you are doing and what you expect to do with the function/list after the insert

Comment: have you thought about creating a class instead..?

Comment: Btw, why do you use a struct instead of a class at all? A smarter _struct_ in this case would be a _class_.

Comment: @DJKRAZE and Tim I can use a class no problem but I don't need any function in this type. but how it will help me make a different objects with different variables. and with less variables.

Comment: Does "smarter" include correct spelling? "hight" should be "height", "cellingoffset" should be "ceilingOffset". Also your casing is inconsistent: "layer2d" and "layer2D". Method names are conventionally Pascal case, i.e., "Insert" not "insert".

Comment: @Charleh What I'm trying to acchive is that inserting parts of a computer into a drawing through an API, each part have a name, file location, etc.. with some default values and some based on user input.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you could benefit from some Inheritance in this case.  Since part is a general type and you have more specific types, such as Monitor and Keyboard, it is the perfect example for inheritance.  So it would look something like this:

```
public class Part
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "not specified"; } }
    public virtual string FileName { get { return "not specified"; } }
    public virtual string Layer2D { get { return "not specified"; } }
    public virtual string Layer3D { get { return "not specified"; } }
    ...
}

public class Monitor : Part
{
    public override FileName { get { return "default monitor"; } }
    public override Layer2D { get { return "default monitor layer"; }}
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class Keyboard : Part
{
    public override FileName { get { return "default keyboard filename.jpg"; } }
    public override Layer2D { get { return "default keyboard 2d layer"; }}
    ...
}
```

You'll find lots of resources out there on Inheritance, and I'd highly recommend looking at them because they will significantly improve your productivity and effectiveness.  Here is one example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Beat me to the punchline Inheritance is the way to go, and since struct do not support such, classes are the way to go.

Comment: Yes. A struct should only be used for immutable types containing only a few fields, because copying the object becomes very expensive otherwise. An alternative would be to let the products implement different interfaces for different facets like `IPart`, `IWarranty`, `IServiceable`.